# How do I create a Storable instance for a recursive type?

Tags: c, haskell, binding, ffi, storable

I have the following data type in a Haskell module and I would like to write a Storable instace to use it with C via FFI :

```hs
data MyType a =
        TypeDouble Double
      | TypeLst [a] 
      | TypeAdd (MyType a) (MyType a)
```

I began by defining the `sizeOf` function :

```hs
instance Storable a => Storable (MyType a)  where
  sizeOf (TypeDouble _) = sizeOf (0 :: Double)
  sizeOf (TypeLst lst)  = sum $ map sizeOf lst
  sizeOf (TypeAdd a b)  = sizeOf a + sizeOf b
```

It compile well, but I don't know how to implement the `peek` and `poke` functions. I thought implementing  these functions the same way as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30550050/3595992) but this implementation work only if all the elements in the list have the same size which is not the case here.

**What is the correct way to implement `peek` and `poke` functions for a recursive type where elements have a floating size ?**

Comment: Maybe you should first define the C type you are expecting to use as the counterpart of your Haskell `MyType a`. Your `sizeOf` seems to be a bit optimistic to me. Your C type will probably need an int/enum/whatever tag that helps you discriminate between the three Haskell constructors; the size of that tag should be added to all the sizes.

Comment: It's worth noting that `sizeOf` has, for historical reasons, the wrong signature. It should actually be [`Tagged a Int`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagged-0.8.5/docs/Data-Tagged.html#t:Tagged) (or `proxy a -> Int`) rather than `a -> Int`. That would make it clear that this can't actually _depend on individual values_, but should be the same for _all_ value of a given type. ([The documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Foreign-Storable.html#v:sizeOf) does say this, though.)

Comment: @leftaroundabout even that signature is now historical. With `TypeApplications` and `AllowAmbigousTypes` it should *really* be `sizeOf :: Storable a => Int`, usable via `sizeOf @a`.

Comment: @HTNW well, yeah, but that's a very recent kind of “historical”. And it can't be made backwards-compatible with old GHC, let alone other Haskell implementations, so this isn't very practical yet for such a low-level feature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can’t have a `Storable` for this. These datatypes need to have a fixed size, just like  C `struct`s. Also, note that `sizeof` isn’t supposed to inspect the value you give it. It’s just a proxy/carrier for the type argument, so you can write e.g. `sizeof (undefined::Int)`. Maybe take a look at [`Foreign.Marshal.Array`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Foreign-Marshal-Array.html)